# Setting Up Audio on a Server Install

Tags: 10.10, server, sound

I'm running on a clean install of 10.10 Server edition and have alsa-base, alsa-tools, alsa-utils, alsaplayer, and alsa-firmware-loader installed. At one point I installed pulseaudio, but I have since removed it.

I've tried the following

```
lspci | grep audio
00:1f.5 Multimedia audio controller: Intel Corporation 82801DB/DBL/DBM (ICH4/ICH4-L/ICH4-M) AC'97 Audio Controller (rev 01)
01:06.0 Multimedia audio controller: Creative Labs [SB Live! Value] EMU10k1X

aplay -l
aplay: device_list:235: no soundcards found...

alsamixer
can not open mixer: No such file or directory
```

When I search for modules with

```
find /lib/modules/`uname -r` | grep snd
```

I do get a list of modules

I'm not very experienced with alsa setup, so I'm not sure where to go from here

Comment: Is there any info regarding sound in the output from these commands: `lsmod` and `dmesg` (lsmod lists modules/drivers loaded, and dmesg displays debug messages from the system kernel.

Answer (score 8):

Adding myself to the user group `audio` solved my problem. I determined this was the problem when

```
sudo aplay -l
```

returned results about the audio card, but

```
aplay -l
```

returned nothing.

Command to run:

```
sudo usermod -aG audio your_username
```

You have to log out to get the change working.

Comment: I'm getting an error `useradd: invalid option -- 'a'`

Answer (score 3):

The first thing to check is that the snd modules are being loaded, please check and report on the output of this command:

`lsmod | grep snd`

If that was the problem, next you should check the audio device available from those with this command:

`cat /proc/asound/cards`

If adding the sound modules doesn't work, then consider checking what hardware you have available with this command:

`lspci | grep Audio`

More information about debugging sound issues can be found here:

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingSoundProblems